# dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier crashes on iPad (with iOS5)

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uitableview

I have a `TableViewController` and a `SearchDisplayController` attached to it. It checks to see if the current `tableView` is search or normal, and then sets the variable as such, then populates the table using this data. Here's the source:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSDictionary *item;
    if(tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView){
        item = [self.search objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    } else {
        item = [self.results objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    /********* ERROR HAPPENS HERE!!!!! **********/
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    /*********************************************/

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

        UIImageView *iconView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5.0, 5.0, 44.0, 44.0)];
        iconView.tag = 100;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:iconView];

        UILabel *title = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(57.0, 5.0, 249.0, 29.0)];
        title.tag = 101;
        title.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"AmericanTypewriter-Bold" size:15.0];
        title.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0f/255.0f green:128.0f/255.0f blue:0.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:title];

        UILabel *subtitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(57.0, 28.0, 249.0, 21.0)];
        subtitle.tag = 102;
        subtitle.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Medium" size:12.0];
        subtitle.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:179.0f/255.0f green:179.0f/255.0f blue:179.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:subtitle];
    } else {
        UIImageView *iconView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
        if([[item valueForKey:@"categories"] count] == 0){
            UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"venue"];
            iconView.frame = CGRectMake(iconView.frame.origin.x, iconView.frame.origin.y, img.size.width, img.size.height);
            [iconView setImage: img];
        } else {
            NSDictionary *iconDict = [[[item valueForKey:@"categories"] objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"icon"];
            NSString *icon = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@bg_44%@", [iconDict valueForKey:@"prefix"], [iconDict valueForKey:@"suffix"]];
            [iconView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:icon] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"venue"]];
        }
        UILabel *title = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
        title.text = [item valueForKey:@"name"];
        UILabel *subtitle = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:102];
        subtitle.text = [[item valueForKey:@"location"] valueForKey:@"address"];
    }
    UIView *bgColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    [bgColorView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:255.0f/255.0f green:128.0f/255.0f blue:0.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0]];
    [cell setSelectedBackgroundView:bgColorView];
    return cell;
}
```

I have been troubled with a bug that crashes the app whenever the code encounters the line where it tries to `dequeueReusableCell`. In most modern iOS devices it works. I've seen it work on my iPhone5, a friend's iPhone4, and a newer version of iPad. However in some devices--including my first generation iPad (with iOS5 installed)--this line just crashes. There is no helpful error message. All I get is that typical "(lldb)" message. Not even an array out of bounds type of exception. The stack trace only shows that it broke inside `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`. Here's the stack trace:

```
2013-03-17 17:32:30.350 Streetgram[861:707] *** Assertion failure in -[UINib lazyArchiveData], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-1914.85/UINib.m:210
2013-03-17 17:32:30:373 Streetgram[861:1799] -[SearchViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] [Line 115] Uncaught exception: UINib must be instantiated with either data or a nib name.
2013-03-17 17:32:30:431 Streetgram[861:1799] -[SearchViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] [Line 116] Stack trace: (
0   CoreFoundation                      0x35c508a7 __exceptionPreprocess + 186
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x33874259 objc_exception_throw + 32
2   CoreFoundation                      0x35c50789 +[NSException raise:format:] + 0
3   Foundation                          0x350443a3 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 90
4   UIKit                               0x335c7a47 -[UINib lazyArchiveData] + 186
5   UIKit                               0x335c7b97 -[UINib unarchiverForInstantiatingReturningError:] + 78
6   UIKit                               0x335c7d8f -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 98
7   UIKit                               0x333b17bd -[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:] + 304
8   Streetgram                          0x00104157 -[SearchViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] + 762
9   UIKit                               0x333b0efb -[UITableView(UITableViewInternal) _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:] + 546
10  UIKit                               0x333affd9 -[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 1076
11  UIKit                               0x333af763 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 206
12  UIKit                               0x33353f15 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 148
13  CoreFoundation                      0x35baf1fb -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 42
14  QuartzCore                          0x32d7aaa5 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 216
15  QuartzCore                          0x32d7a6bd _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 216
16  QuartzCore                          0x32d7e843 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 226
17  QuartzCore                          0x32d7e57f _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 314
18  QuartzCore                          0x32d764b9 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 56
19  CoreFoundation                      0x35c24b1b __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 18
20  CoreFoundation                      0x35c22d57 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 258
21  CoreFoundation                      0x35c230b1 __CFRunLoopRun + 760
22  CoreFoundation                      0x35ba64a5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 300
23  CoreFoundation                      0x35ba636d CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
24  GraphicsServices                    0x33941439 GSEventRunModal + 136
25  UIKit                               0x3337ecd5 UIApplicationMain + 1080
26  Streetgram                          0x001007c9 main + 116
27  Streetgram                          0x00100750 start + 40
    ....
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: I don't see any stack trace here.

Comment: Sometimes I've found it helpful to continue execution after a break like this (using Command-Option-Y, iirc).  It will just break again, but often the debug log will then have a message in it describing the problem.  For example, yours seems to be failing with an unsupported message being sent to the cell, continuing may give you the name of the message that failed in the debug log.

Comment: I've added the actual stack trace here. Thank you for pointing out.

Comment: what happens if you always recreate the cell?

Comment: It does succeed in displaying the cells if I don't reuse the cells, but then the segue doesn't work. But I think that may be another issue, or not?

Answer (score 2):

When you dequeue the reusable cell you should use the tableView that was passed in the parameter instead of your own known self.tableView.  For a search view those two won't be the same which might cause problems.  Like this:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

Comment: Ah sorry, I was trying all kinds of approaches and ended up with that self.tableView, but initially it was tableView. just switched back to tableView but this doesn't work either.

Comment: there is something funny about the creation of the uitablecell, as the error shows. setImageWithURL, are you using AFNetworking?

Answer (score 1):

Finally found a solution (I don't even know the details of why it works but it works). Turns out, you have to uncheck 'use autolayout' settings in certain cases. http://www.seifeet.com/2012/12/ios-nib-data-is-invalid-exception-with.html

Comment: Probably because auto layout is iOS 6 only. You should edit your answer to better reflect what you did rather than rely on a link, so that the answer stands alone.

Comment: Duh. Autolayout is iOS 6 only. Strange the compiler lets you even build this for an iOS 5 target